# actionscript 3.0 get if the main timeline is playing or stopped.. is there any way?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im new to AS3. I very much wonder, if there is a way to get information from main timeline, if it's plaing or stopped (without variables). I was searching through the web, tutorials etc. so far, cannot find an answer. Here's my "pseudo code"

```
if(maintimeline == stopped){
    run some function();
}

or...

if(maintimeline == playing){
    run some function();
}
```

And the problem is to get that playing or stopped property. I cannot find it anywhere. So I will be very glad if someone can help me with that problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693414/determine-is-movieclip-playing-now

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

Since Flash 11 you can use isPlaying property on MovieClip (and your main timeline is a MovieClip), check the doc : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#isPlaying

**Question 2:**

```
// Recursivly play or stop (apply it to stage or a random movieclip)
public function playOrStop(target : DisplayObjectContainer, doPlay : Boolean) : void
{
    for(var i : uint = 0; i < target.numChildren; ++i)
    {
        var currentDo : DisplayObject = target.getChildAt( i );

        // If current clip is a Movieclip, apply play or stop
        if( currentDo is MovieClip )
            doPlay ? MovieClip( currentDo ).play() : MovieClip( currentDo ).stop();

        // If current can contains sub clip, then check inside
        if( currentDo is DisplayObjectContainer )
            playOrStop( currentDo as DisplayObjectContainer, doPlay);
    }
}
```